# How to add comment inside the return statement in render function?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any possibilities we can add our comment inside the return statement in render functionality. For example find below the code snippet.

```js
 render: function() {
    var value = this.state.value;
    return (
        <div>                         
            <input type="text" value={value} />
            <select value="B">
                <option value="A">Apple</option>
                <option value="B">Banana</option>
                <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
            </select>
        </div>); 
    ...
```

In the above code, I want to add my comment next to the `<input>` tag like `Read-Only Textbox. Because it does not have onChange Event`. How can i add it?

Comment: {/* React only works with block comments. */} Just put block comments inside of "code" blocks.

Comment: a comment that will be rendered to DOM?

Comment: No it will not rendered  to DOM @Davin

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add comments in render like that : `{/* COMMENT */}`

Answer (score 3):

Use like this `{/*comment*/}` 
working [demo](http://jsbin.com/pohoqevamo/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

To add a comment within JSX you should use curly braces (`{}`) to start an [expression](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) and then within that you can write a block comment (`/**/`).

```
return (
  <div>
    {/* comment */}
  </div>
)
```

This works regardless of whether you're within a return statement:

```
const retVal = (
  <div>
    {/* comment */}
  </div>
)
return retVal
```

Note that the following is not possible because you cannot open a JSX expression *outside* of a JSX element:

```
return (
  {/* comment */}
  <div></div>
)
```

Instead you would simply do it the normal way:

```
return (
  // comment
  <div></div>
)
```